# Ionic 6: ion-header & ion-footer transition animation between components out of sync with ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]

---

I am using a ion-router-outlet with "animated=true". When navigating between two components, the transition animation is behaving strangely:

- The ion-header & ion-footer appear before the the transition animation (when navigating from component A to component B).
- The ion-header & ion-footer disappear after the transition animation visually completes (when navigating backwards, from component B back to component A).

Both of these effects can be seen in this short video. Pay attention to the red background, which appears & disappears out of sync with the animation.

I was expect to see the ion-header & footer both appear and disappear in sync with the animation between components.

I've seen this issue talked about in other issues & elsewhere online. For example:

- Both the ion-header & ion-footer have nested ion-toolbars in them which [I've read should fix this type of issue](https://github.com/RC4): `ion-footer's content not animated with custom component #9947`.

If anyone has any idea how to solve this issue please do let me know - thanks in advance!

---

For a minimal code reproduction, please see this repo: https://github.com/drakedeatonuk/reproduction

to reproduce:

1. pull the reproduction repo:
2. run `npx nx serve app`
3. navigate to localhost:4200/home/tab
4. click on the 'Page link' button
5. click on the "Back" button

---

Config Info:

```
Ionic CLI : 6.20.6 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 6.2.8 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@ionic/angular)
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.0.5 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular)
@angular-devkit/schematics : 15.0.4 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics)
@angular/cli : 15.0.5 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@angular/cli)
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 5.0.3 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit)
Capacitor CLI : 4.6.1
@capacitor/android : 4.6.1 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@capacitor/android)
@capacitor/core : 4.6.1 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@capacitor/core)
@capacitor/ios : 4.6.1 (/Users/drakedeaton/Code/cc-reproduction/node_modules/@capacitor/ios)
cordova-res : not installed globally
native-run : 1.7.1
NodeJS : v18.13.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 9.3.1
OS : macOS
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the ion-header, ion-content and ion-footer first in your code and next have your component to have the transitions like:

```
<ion-content>
  <app-component-content></app-component-content>
</ion-content>
```